# Javascript autoclick not working

Tags: javascript

I am using a script to make tables in html sortable. The script is here- http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/. I want the text which sorts the html table to be clicked automatically when the i loaded. The autoclick script i am using is this-

```
<head>
<script LANGUAGE='javascript'>
function autoClick(){
document.getElementById('sort').click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="autoClick();">
<table><tr><th><p id="sort">Click here to sort the table</p></th>...
```

The problem is that this is not working and i am confused that why this isnt working.

--------------------EDIT------------------

Sorry for this but actually i was typing something wrong in the body onload statement. Thus the script i was using was correct.

Comment: See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D7Abd/1/ .. Make sure u add the jQuery library, Also classname 'sortable' to the table

Answer (score 1):

Where have you defined your event? 
Because I see juste one function in your onload.

Below, a little example which work fine:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        var init = function() 
        {
            document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
                alert('Auto test is ok');
            }, false);
        };

        function autoClick(){
            document.getElementById('test').click();
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init(); autoClick();">
        <button id="test">Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always safer to use Jquery library. Just include the latest Jquery library on your header section of the page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this function Should solve your issue:

```
$("#sort").live('click');
```

Comment: Why 1.7 when there is 1.8 out there? And btw `live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the class name in the table

Please add your table tag with class name called "sortable".